# Repeat a character while the Button is held down

Tags: android

I want to print a letter over and over as long as a button is held down.
For example, if I push <kbd>R</kbd> for 2 seconds I should see: 
`"RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"`

I tried this:

```
public void addListenerOnUP() {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String p = "R";

            //print ...
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

But it only works when the user moves their finger, not while they are touching the screen. How can I get "R" to repeat?

Comment: Please rephrase your problem, as I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's work when move the finger
>   i want use it without moveing

You need to use a callback.  By using a Handler and Runnable you can print out a new letter on a set interval while the user's finger is down. (Perhaps once every 100 milliseconds?)

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Print out your letter here...

        // Call the runnable again
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```

Only print letters while the user's finger is down:

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Start printing the letter in the callback now 
            handler.post(runnable);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Stop printing the letter
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: `handler` and `runnable` are class variables. Add them inside your class, but outside `onCreate()`.